MABS Server running out of disk space - Can we relocate the backups? (to expand underlying storage pool)
We have a Microsoft Azure Backup server that is running low on disk space.
The Server is WS2022, running latest version of MABS. It has 8 drive bays, 6 of which are currently in use (6x2.4TB).  It is setup using modern backup storage (JBOD disks with Windows handling the storage pool and a big VHD on top)
I have purchased two more drives and installed them, however I am unable to expand the VHD.  Some research has shown this is because the 'number of columns' is 3, meaning I need to install disks in groups of 3.  This is physically impossible as there aren't enough bays in the server.
So, is it possible to move/copy the MABS backup replicas off of the server, recreate the VDH, and put them back again (without breaking MABS)?
Thanks.
